# crond doesn't work in docker with vanilla alpine

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

After googling around for two hours on how to make cron work within an alpine docker image  I'm still none the wiser. Here's for everyone to reproduce:

```
docker pull alpine:latest
docker run -d --rm alpine crond -f -l 8
```

This will start the cron daemon in alpine as the main process.

You can then opt into the container to see what changes:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> sh
```

Add some changes to crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

then add this line in for example (make sure to terminate with a newline as cron needs it):

```
* * * * * echo $(date '+\%s') > /tmp/log.txt
```

This should write to /tmp/log.txt the epoch time in seconds every minute.

Then watch it not do anything:

```
watch cat /tmp/log.txt
```

And my question is just: Why does it not work? I can see with `ps aux` that `crond` is running. Unfortunately there don't seem to be any logfiles associated with cron on alpine, are there?

Comment: When I try to reproduce your issue, it works as it should. I made one change. On your `exec` command you have `--it`. It should be `-it`. That's probably just a typo though. Also, I didn't use `watch` to look for changes. I just used `cat`.

Comment: @HansKilian That's peculiar. I really did exactly this and it's _not_ working. Can I ask you what operating system you're running this on?

Comment: I'm using an Ubuntu 22.04 Hyper-V VM on Windows 11. x86_64 architecture.

Comment: For me exactly same commands u used are working :)

Comment: you can also make sure without watch command, maybe it is problem with watch command

Comment: Indeed i tried it and it is working on wsl2/ubuntu 22.04. However when I ran it on Ubuntu 22.04 natively it doesn't. Also it doesn't work on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.1. However this is when I build the image on ubuntu22.04 first..